# AttributeError: 'ElephasEstimator' object has no attribute 'setFeaturesCol'

Tags: apache-spark, keras, pyspark, classification, elephas

I am trying yo run a Keras model for a binary text classification using Elephas in Apache Spark. Below is the my code:

```
     #my initial spark statements
     from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
     from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
     conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Elephas_App').setMaster('local[4]')
     sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
     sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
     #SQLcontext is created using sc for realational functionality
     sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

    #elephas estimator parameters
    optimizer_conf = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.01)
    opt_conf = optimizers.serialize(optimizer_conf)

    estimator = ElephasEstimator()
    estimator.set_keras_model_config(model.to_yaml())
    estimator.set_categorical_labels(True)
    estimator.set_nb_classes(tar_class)
    estimator.set_num_workers(1)
    estimator.set_epochs(5)
    estimator.set_batch_size(64)
    estimator.setFeaturesCol("features")
    estimator.setLabelCol("label")
    estimator.set_verbosity(1)
    estimator.set_validation_split(0.10)
    estimator.set_optimizer_config(opt_conf)
    estimator.set_mode("synchronous")
    estimator.set_loss("binary_crossentrophy")
    estimator.set_metrics(["acc"])
```

I am facing with the following issue:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-92-74397f47b924> in <module>()
           7 estimator.set_epochs(5)
           8 estimator.set_batch_size(64)
           ----> 9 estimator.setFeaturesCol("features")
           10 estimator.setLabelCol("label")
           11 estimator.set_verbosity(1)

     AttributeError: 'ElephasEstimator' object has no attribute 'setFeaturesCol'
```

This issue exists for both "setFeaturesCol" and "setLabelCol".

Can anyone please help me as I am new to this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `HasLabelCol` and `HasFeaturesCols` mixins were changed in Spark 3.0.x+ to remove the setter methods, hence the issue. The `featuresCol` and `labelCol` can be supplied in the `ElephasEstimator` constructor:

```
ElephasEstimator(featuresCol='features', labelCol='label')
```

However, in your application, this shouldn't be necessary, as the default feature column is 'features' and the default label column is 'label' - you should be able to omit those lines and run as normal.